# Receiving "Redirect_URI" Is NOT Valid Error With Outlook Contacts REST API?

Tags: outlook-restapi

I integrated the following **Outlooks Contacts API** with my website this way users with a **hotmail.com, outlook.com, msn.com, windows live email address can easily connect to their contacts**.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/contacts-rest-operations#Getcontacts

However, I keep on receiving this error when I try to log in to my hotmail email account:

*The provided value for the input parameter "redirect_uri" is not valid. The expected value is "https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf" or a URL which matches the redirect URI registered for this client application.*

Does anyone know what is causing this issue?

I created my app credentials again but it still doesn't work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The redirect needs to match the redirect you specified when you registered your application. This should be a URL in your web app that receives auth codes.

Comment: I need an jar (which will be a Spring Boot App) that needs to read attachments of a particular email account

There username and password are pre-seeded in app. So No User needs intervening for consent. 

No web App but only Two REST endpoints:
1. which will recieve getAttachment() request from MyJarConsumer
2. Redirect Endpoint to recieve auth Code

How to recieve the auth code ?

Dummy U/P:  arnab30dutta@outlook.com / wiproinfotechbt012
App Name SpringBootMailRESTApiApp
Client Id 7a1fff16-ef39-4299-a6b9-50d2b37924e4
Client_secret   8wLwBic9Hxwj9f9e5hkjq9n